# TTTAttributedLabel, not able to run on iOS 5.1 device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode5, tttattributedlabel

I am trying to run an app with a deployment target of `iOS 5.1`, on a device with the same `iOS` version. I am running it from `Xcode 5` and I have added `TTTAttributedLabel` to my project for attributed strings. But when I run it, it gives me the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel setAttributedText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x395670'

I have not run an app on an `iOS 5.1` device before using `Xcode 5`, so I am not sure where the problem lies. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Error means you actually created instance of UILabel, not TTTAttributedLabel. Check how you create your label

Comment: Yes. You're right. That was exactly the problem. How silly of me to not notice!